# Why am I getting "killall -q -USR1 udhcpd" error message?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, archlinux

I have a router with me. It always shows the following debug message:

```
killall -q -USR1 udhcpd
```

Can anyone explain to me what is happening here? Why am I getting such an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`killall` is used to kill a process by name.  It sends a signal to all process running by that name.  If no signal is specified, `SIGTERM` is sent.  However, it is not in this case.  It is used to send the `USR1` signal to udhcpd.  According to udhcpd, signal `USR1` by default is to trigger a forced write to the lease file.

Reference: [busybox udhcpd source code](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/udhcp/dhcpd.c#n434)